# Update wxs file from xslt file

Tags: xml, xslt, wix

I'm use heat.exe utility from wix toolset for generate wxs file on my folder. And now I need update generated wxs file my values form xslt file.

Generated wxs file

**Input xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="RFolder">
            <Directory Id="dir8A1C71C28CB2FBCD880BDF1115CE4C9E" Name="de" />
            <Directory Id="dir75CE436C7AA3432555A9E4DF401C2182" Name="ea" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="RComponents">
            <Component Id="cmp85BD6E6D48A917B8EC794CCCAC0E01D3" Directory="dir1149222D61DE053C3631D19DB46C305B" Guid="10339506-F2E3-40EF-82AA-4F21CE23DE2B">

                <File Id="fil2A0EE991AFD039C2716E112172877836" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.RFolderVar)\ea\doc.ini" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp318CD297C8EB9EF822C05002107F6F5D" Directory="dir0424E347D4FE768AB1DDE05B6A26D9F9" Guid="6CC9AB04-D367-4E85-9174-A6776968F7EB">

                <File Id="filF51143C322B265B0A2E0732F68A10D58" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.RFolderVar)\de\set.ini" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir8A1C71C28CB2FBCD880BDF1115CE4C9E">
            <Directory Id="dir0424E347D4FE768AB1DDE05B6A26D9F9" Name="system" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir75CE436C7AA3432555A9E4DF401C2182">
            <Directory Id="dir1149222D61DE053C3631D19DB46C305B" Name="Runner" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

My input xslt file, when I doing generation condition what be installed on machine

**Input xslt:**

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

            <xsl:template match="wix:Wix">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
              <xsl:apply-templates />
            </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="wix:Component">

        <!-- Just copy the tag itself -->
        <xsl:copy>

          <xsl:variable name="fvsys" >
            <xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='File']/@Source"/>
          </xsl:variable>


          <!-- Copy all attributes -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
          <!--<xsl:attribute name="Name">RecoveryMedia</xsl:attribute>-->
          <!-- This will mark all files in the WebConfig folder as permanent -->
          <xsl:choose>
            <!-- Note that the string is translated to all lower case, so you don't have to care about being case sensitive or not -->
            <xsl:when test="contains($fvsys, 'ea\')">
              <!-- Here we will add the Permanent-attribute to this very special component -->
              <xsl:element name="Condition" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[INSTALLATION_LANGUAGE_PACK=&quot;ea&quot;]]&gt;</xsl:text>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>

           <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($fvsys, 'de\')">

              <xsl:element name="Condition" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
                <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[INSTALLATION_LANGUAGE_PACK=&quot;de&quot;]]&gt;</xsl:text>
              </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose> 

          <!-- Now take the rest of the inner tag -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
        </xsl:copy>  

        </xsl:template>  
        <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Actual results:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="RFolder">
            <Directory Id="dir8A1C71C28CB2FBCD880BDF1115CE4C9E" Name="de" />
            <Directory Id="dir75CE436C7AA3432555A9E4DF401C2182" Name="ea" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="RComponents">
            <Component Id="cmp85BD6E6D48A917B8EC794CCCAC0E01D3" Directory="dir1149222D61DE053C3631D19DB46C305B" Guid="10339506-F2E3-40EF-82AA-4F21CE23DE2B">
                <Condition><![CDATA[INSTALLATION_LANGUAGE_PACK="ea"]]></Condition>
                <File Id="fil2A0EE991AFD039C2716E112172877836" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.RFolderVar)\ea\doc.ini" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp318CD297C8EB9EF822C05002107F6F5D" Directory="dir0424E347D4FE768AB1DDE05B6A26D9F9" Guid="6CC9AB04-D367-4E85-9174-A6776968F7EB">
                <Condition><![CDATA[INSTALLATION_LANGUAGE_PACK="de"]]></Condition>
                <File Id="filF51143C322B265B0A2E0732F68A10D58" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.RFolderVar)\de\set.ini" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir8A1C71C28CB2FBCD880BDF1115CE4C9E">
            <Directory Id="dir0424E347D4FE768AB1DDE05B6A26D9F9" Name="system" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="dir75CE436C7AA3432555A9E4DF401C2182">
            <Directory Id="dir1149222D61DE053C3631D19DB46C305B" Name="Runner" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

**Expected results:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="RFolder">
            <Directory Id="dir8A1C71C28CB2FBCD880BDF1115CE4C9E" Name="de" />
            <Directory Id="dir75CE436C7AA3432555A9E4DF401C2182" Name="ea" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="RComponents">
            <Component Id="cmp85BD6E6D48A917B8EC794CCCAC0E01D3" Directory="dir1149222D61DE053C3631D19DB46C305B" Guid="10339506-F2E3-40EF-82AA-4F21CE23DE2B">
                <Condition><![CDATA[INSTALLATION_LANGUAGE_PACK="ea"]]></Condition>
                <File Id="fil2A0EE991AFD039C2716E112172877836" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.RFolderVar)\ea\doc.ini" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="cmp318CD297C8EB9EF822C05002107F6F5D" Directory="dir0424E347D4FE768AB1DDE05B6A26D9F9" Guid="6CC9AB04-D367-4E85-9174-A6776968F7EB">
                <Condition><![CDATA[INSTALLATION_LANGUAGE_PACK="de"]]></Condition>
                <File Id="filF51143C322B265B0A2E0732F68A10D58" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.RFolderVar)\de\set.ini" />
            </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="RFolder">
            <Directory Id="dir0424E347D4FE768AB1DDE05B6A26D9F9" Name="system" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="RFolder">
            <Directory Id="dir1149222D61DE053C3631D19DB46C305B" Name="Runner" />
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I don't know how change all Id's from rool DirectoryRef new value... Maybe somebody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of the logic, but first try adding an `xsl:key` to the stylesheet

```
 <xsl:key name="Directories" match="wix:Directory" use="@Id" />
```

Then adding the following template match, to match `DirectoryRef` that have an `id` that is present on `Directory` element.

```
<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef/@Id[key('Directories', .)]">
    <xsl:attribute name="Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('Directories', .)/../@Id" />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

See it in action at http://xsltransform.net/bEzjRKs

EDIT: In answer to your comment, I am not quite sure what you mean by "overwrite Id's in DirectoryRef which linked on Directory Id's in first DirectroyRef on this `<DirectoryRef Id="RFolder">`, but try updating the `xsl:key` to one of these instead:

```
<xsl:key name="Directories" match="wix:DirectoryRef[@Id='RFolder']/wix:Directory" use="@Id" />

<xsl:key name="Directories" match="wix:Fragment[1]/wix:DirectoryRef/wix:Directory" use="@Id" />

<xsl:key name="Directories" match="wix:DirectoryRef[not(preceding::wix:DirectoryRef)]/wix:Directory" use="@Id" />
```

Comment: very close man, but not what I want. If I use this code I get overwrite all Id's . But I want overwrite Id's in DirectoryRef which linked on Directory Id's in first DirectroyRef on this `<DirectoryRef Id="RFolder">`